# Which deb should be used to install linux kernel?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kernel, dpkg, compiling

I built linux kernel on ubuntu machine first time. Total 13 deb packages were produced by build process at my local machine. 
I could not figure-out which deb should be installed to run 4.4 kernel. What is purpose of these debs. Could you please me to figure it out?

```
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-59_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-common_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-doc_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-59_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-source-4.4.0_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-tools-4.4.0-59_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-tools-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-tools-common_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-59_4.4.0-59.80_all.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic_4.4.0-59.80_amd64.deb
```

This will install Linux image and headers. Other packages are needed in specific cases and are not usually installed.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, accept it by clicking the check sign at the left.

Comment: Thanks for reply!  I am novice so looking for trivial question.  
As per suggestion, I tried to upgrade ubuntu 3.13  kernel to 4.4 using these 4 pkgs only. But it failed on kmod dependency.
While installing kmod using apt-get, I got following error on 3.13 machine:
 sudo apt-get install kmod
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package kmod is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source.

Comment: This is a different question.